# Plot multiple time series in a x-y-coordinate system with matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got multiple time series all of equal length.

After doing some magic tricks I get vector representations for these time series. I cluster them and reduce the dimensionality of these vectors to 2D-vectors with TSNE.

Now I got a 2D representation of my time series and so far I plotted them as points in 2D-space.

Is there a way to plot the time series at the position of the 2d-vectors in a coordinate system?

Excuse my bad paint skills but it should show the idea. Every colored line is a time series that gets plotted at the x-y-position of the corresponding 2d-vector representation and is colored by it's cluster membership

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a somewhat acceptable solution. But I need to scale the vectors between 0 and 1.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.inset_locator import inset_axes

x = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)
y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-x)
y2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x)
y3 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

positions = [(0.1, 0.3), (0.8, 0.7), (0.3, 0.4)]
time_series = [y1, y2, y3]
colors = ["red", "green", "red"]
cmap = cm.hot
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
for v, ts, c in zip(positions, time_series, colors):
    axins = inset_axes(ax, width="100%", height="100%", loc='upper left',
                   bbox_to_anchor=(v[0],v[1],.1,.1), bbox_transform=ax.transAxes)
    axins.plot(range(len(ts)), ts, c)
    axins.axis("off")
    axins.patch.set_alpha(0)
```

[image]